# Getting app user data in graph api v2, using global IDs

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

So version 2 of Facebook's graph API introduces app-specific IDs, to protect user privacy from spam or something like that. But they said that users who have added your app in v1 using a global ID will continue to send you their global ID in v2, to keep your app backward compatible.

This is all fine, but v2 of the api also forbids getting user data with global IDs. A call to the graph with global IDs from inside a canvas app gives an exception saying to use the app-specific ID instead.

I'm kind of at a loss here. I'm trying to get the basic information of a random subset of my app's users, to display to the current user, who isn't necessarily a friend. But most of my users have global IDs stored in my database because they joined a long time ago. It seems like if my app were new, all of the IDs stored in my database would be app-specific, and so I would be able to get their info. This indicates to me that it's not Facebook's intent to forbid me from getting the data I want. It's just impossible for me because of the unfortunate situation of having an old app.

Is there any way for me to get this data? I know I can revert to v1 of the graph but that will go away on April 30, 2015. I only want the most basic info, and I'm only displaying names.

I am using version 4 of the PHP SDK. My request looks like this:

```
(new FacebookRequest(
            self::$session, 'GET', '',
            array('ids' => implode(',', $userIds))
        ))->execute()->getGraphObjectList(GraphUser::className());
```

My session comes from calling `getSession` on the `FacebookCanvasLoginHelper` as shown in their docs, so I have a new access token and signed request.

### edit

So, I rescind my question, because I'm dumb. Sahil is right. My problem was that I'm working in a separate app for testing (not an official test app, but an app I created a long time ago for testing) so the app IDs in question haven't actually added the app, so I can't get their info. Oops. Good reason to migrate to an official test app.

### edit again

I un-rescind my question. Facebook is dumb. I created an official test app tied to my real app, and it is giving me an app-specific ID for myself, not the one given for the main app. I check out the page I had trouble with before, and the same exception:

```
Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException: The global ID 693041250 is not allowed.
Please use the application specific ID instead.
```

The dev page on test apps says:

- Test Apps **share the same app-scoped User ID namespace** as your production app making it simpler to debug issues with app-scoped IDs, or in cases where you use a copy of your production database for development.

This appears to be blatantly incorrect. I'm using a copy of my production database. I know my Facebook ID. It wouldn't even give my own ID that was given for the production app, let alone anyone else's. Does this new thing only work for brand new apps or something? I'm about ready to abandon Facebook development at this point for things like this.

Comment: What is the API call that you do and what access token are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that-

> users who have added your app in v1 using a global ID will continue to send you their global ID in v2, to keep your app backward compatible.

But this is incorrect: *but v2 of the api also forbids getting user data with global IDs. A call to the graph with global IDs from inside a canvas app gives an exception saying to use the app-specific ID instead.*

Of-course you'll get the user data with id returned by v2 API (be it global-id or app-specific-id).

Sorry but I don't really understand the SDK's syntax you've used (I don't like using SDKs), but I'm sure this will work. You can even test this in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), just *select your app* from (top-middle) drop-down and call `/v2/{user-id}` of a v1 user and this will get you the result. You must be doing something wrong in your code.